Laravel 10 Mailtrap Livewire mail not being sent
For forgot password page, I have a form that takes in input from the user and needs to send an email to the user for reset password link, but the page goes unresponsive for a minute and gives enter image description here
I am using Laravel 10 with Livewire.
The .env file contains
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"


also the ForgotPasswordPage.php contains
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
use Livewire\Component;

#[Title('Forgot Password')]

class ForgotPasswordPage extends Component
{
    public $email;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|exists:users,email',
        ]);
        
        // dd($this->email);
        $status = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $this->email]);
        dd($status);

        if($status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
            session()->flash('success', 'Password reset link sent on your email id.');
            $this->email = '';  //reset email field
        } else {
            session()->flash('error', 'Something went wrong. Please try again.');
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.forgot-password-page');
    }
}


Also the web.php contains
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', LoginPage::class)->name('login');
    Route::get('/register', RegisterPage::class);
    Route::get('/forgot', ForgotPasswordPage::class)->name('password.request');
    Route::get('/reset/{token}', ResetPasswordPage::class)->name('password.reset');
});


I tried clearing the cache for the laravel apllication, I also tried dd to check whether the save method is recieving the mail. The method is recieving the mail, and on checking the db, the password reset table also contains a new entry with the email used and the token generated.

You should check .env configs. Some of mailtrap values do not seem right. MAIL_HOST should be smtp.mailtrap.io without sandbox.  MAIL_USERNAME MAIL_PASSWORD should be in the format 587f56.... and c6784..., not plain username, password values.
Also mail encryption MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

I tried your suggestion, and still it gives Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded error, I had the real value for the username and password, just edited them for the post. Also, the code given by mailtrap for laravel 9+ contained sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io.

It looks like you are encountering a connection timeout.
This might mean that:

the service is offline - then the timeout should be temporary

your provider or local firewall rules block outgoing connections on port 2525.
This could mean an aggressively configured firewall, or possibly spam protection. You might need to talk to your hosting provider or systems administrator about relaxing these restrictions.


Try telnet sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io 2525 to see if you can establish a connection to the service.
